# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, getproperty

```
package com.merchantPlatform;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class MerchantPlatformTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium WebDriver\\geckodriver\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

        // Initialize WebDriver
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

         /* This works fine for versions lesser than Selenium 3. For Selenium 3 and higher, it will throw java.lang.IllegalStateException */

        // Maximize Window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Wait For Page To Load
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Navigate to MerchantPlatform URL
        driver.get("http://localhost:52939/");

    }

}
```

Error

I am getting the below exception with `System.getProperty`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
>         at com.merchantPlatform.MerchantPlatformTest.main(MerchantPlatformTest.java:20)

Comment: remove the spaces in the directory name of the webdrivers and try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use System.setProperty not the System.getProperty as follows.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "C:\\Selenium WebDriver\\geckodriver\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you are using wrong syntax, to opening the browser.

Instead of using `System.getProperty`, You have to use `System.setProperty` as mentioned below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium WebDriver\\geckodriver\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
```

For more details on this issue, refer this [page](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/launching-firefox-browser-with-geckodriver-selenium-3).

Comment: Thanks.. It was setProperty, works fine now.. I tried to mark both your answers correct, but unable to do.. Though I searched a lot for this error, I missed the set part.